# Import CSV file into multiple tables in D365

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory, dynamics-365, import-csv

I'm searching for a no-code solution to import data from a single CSV file into multiple tables in D365, in a single data import process.
OOB Import Data in D365 can only import data into a single table, not in multiple table, in one shot.
Do you think Azure Data Factory can be used for this task?

What other alternatives can I take, please?

Thanks in advance for your time and knowledge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ADF pipelines (Dataflow) with multiple sources and load data into Dynamics. [Read more](https://medium.com/capgemini-microsoft-team/using-azure-data-factory-v2-to-load-microsoft-dynamics-365-crm-from-text-file-771ce7df2dd6) and [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74761195/how-azure-data-factory-dataflow-can-create-crm-related-entities-records-in-sing)

Alternatives are [configuration migration utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/manage-configuration-data?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422) and [Data import using zip file](https://support.cobalt.net/hc/en-us/articles/4410824948763-Import-Data-Into-CRM#importing-multiple-records)

All these are not full fledged ETL tools, so hiccups are possible, even roadblocks considering your no code requirement.

You can try SSIS+Kingswaysoft or Scribe as an option considering [Import wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/data-platform-import-export?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422) is not getting much attention in the Dataverse product.

Comment: Thank you very much for a lot of good info!
ADF is my first choice.

Answer (score 0):

XrmToolbox Field Creator tool is a life savior. It's free and does the job.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).